# Python zeep how to send multiple values ​in one request

Tags: python, zeep

I apologize right away for my poor English.

I have a problem with sending multiple values ​​via zeep client. There is a conditional method

```
<s:element name="GetSomething">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="id" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

If I need to get 1 value, then there is no problem. I am using this code:

```
WSDL = 'example.asmx?WSDL'

session = Session()
transport = Transport(session=session)
client = Client(wsdl=WSDL, transport=transport)
res = client.service.GetCompanyExtendedReport(id='1')
print(res)
```

but if i need to get multiple values. I will give an example xml

```
<s11:Envelope xmlns:s11='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <s11:Body>
    <ns1:GetSomething xmlns:ns1='http://examplesoapapi.ru/idk'>
      <ns1:id>1</ns1:id>
      <ns1:id>2</ns1:id>
      <ns1:id>3</ns1:id>
      <ns1:id>4</ns1:id>
      <ns1:id>5</ns1:id>
    </ns1:GetStateContractReport>
  </s11:Body>
</s11:Envelope>
```

then I don't understand how can I send this kind of request via zeep

```
WSDL = 'example.asmx?WSDL'

session = Session()
transport = Transport(session=session)
client = Client(wsdl=WSDL, transport=transport)
res = client.service.GetCompanyExtendedReport(id='1', id='2', id='3', ???)
print(res)
```

it's clear that I can send such requests in a loop, but this is not what I need...

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Your `id` element is defined as:

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="id" type="s:string"/>
```

That means zero or one `id`. [Not more](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints).

You either need to make a loop for more calls, or you look for another operation within your service that accepts a list of `id`s, not just zero or one (if that even exists).

Even if you make a call like in your example, the service will either use one at most or it will reject the request entirely, simply because SOAP is a protocol and a SOAP service has a specific contract defined. It accepts requests that conform to that contract, not requests that you wish you would have ([read this for an extended explanation](https://d-petre-bogdan.medium.com/the-wsdl-is-not-the-soap-web-service-97f307c4a90b)).